# Github action: Post comment to PR with pylint result

Tags: pipe, github-actions, pylint

I am setting up my github CI pipeline, currently I am trying to setup pylint to be ran automatically on pull requests.  How do I write the results from pylint into a PR comment?

This is what I have.  I try to use the github action on mshick/add-pr-comment@v1.  However, I am not sure how to pipe the result from the previous step.  Is it possible to only write the final score instead of the whole result, because it's very long.

```
name: Python Linting

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, dev ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Lint with pylint
      run: |
        pip install pylint
        pylint ./src --exit-zero
    - name: Post result to PR
    - uses: mshick/add-pr-comment@v1
      with:
        message: |
          **Hello**
        repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        repo-token-user-login: 'github-actions[bot]' # The user.login for temporary GitHub tokens
        allow-repeats: false # This is the default
```

This is my pylint result, at least he last line, the full result is really long:

```
-----------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 3.31/10
```

Comment: You could add the OUTPUT (or part of it) from the pylint command in the `GITHUB_ENV` through a variable, and then use `${{ env.OUTPUT }}` in the message from the add-pr-comment action.

Comment: Is it possible to only use the last 2 lines?  Can you write an answer and provide an example?

Comment: You would have to use a shell command (which I don't know) to extract just the part you want (e.g: _Your code has been rated at 3.31/10_). So you would have `OUTPUT=$(pylint ./src --exit-zero)`, then something to extract the part you want from the $OUTPUT variable into another variable, let's say MESSAGE. Then add the var to env using `echo "MESSAGE=$MESSAGE" >> $GITHUB_ENV` (all of this on the `Lint with pylint` step). Then, finally, use `${{ env.MESSAGE }}` in the add-pr-comment action, instead of _Hello_.

Comment: I add it as answer to make it easier to understand :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you would have to use a script or a shell command (which I don't know as it depends on the context) to extract just the part of the command output you want (*e.g: Your code has been rated at 3.31/10*), then add it as env variable (or output) to use it in the next step.

I would do something like this in your job:

```yaml
    - name: Lint with pylint
      run: |
        pip install pylint
        OUTPUT=$(pylint ./src --exit-zero)
        #OUTPUT=$(shell command or script to extract the part your want)
        echo "MESSAGE=$OUTPUT" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: Post result to PR
      uses: mshick/add-pr-comment@v1
      with:
        message: ${{ env.MESSAGE }}
        repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        repo-token-user-login: 'github-actions[bot]' # The user.login for temporary GitHub tokens
        allow-repeats: false # This is the default
```

Where the `echo "MESSAGE=$OUTPUT" >> $GITHUB_ENV` would add the MESSAGE to the github context environment, to be able to use in the next step with `${{ env.MESSAGE }}`.

Comment: Can you modify your ansewr to escape $OUTPUT_PART?  It's throwing error saying:  Error: Unable to process file command 'env' successfully.
Error: Invalid environment variable format 'src/clean.py:8:0: C0304: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)'

Comment: I commented the OUTPUT_PART variable, so it should take the whole command OUTPUT as MESSAGE (if the format allows it. As I generally use it for small string, I don't know if there is a character size limit).

Comment: alright thanks, I will ask how to get the tail in a separate question.

Comment: `OUTPUT` is a multiline string that causes parsing errors when GitHub tries to read `env`. Use this syntax for multiline variables https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings